# How can i write my own matlab code to degrade an image by atmospheric turbulence function

Tags: matlab

How can I write a degradation function in Matlab to yield a degraded image?

But I want a degraded image by atmospheric turbulence.

Here below is the function

```
H(u,v)=e^(-k(u^2 + v^2)^5/6)
```

so how can I express this in Matlab?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please next time don't tag unrelated languages. I fixed that for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try some Matlab functions which allow you to blur the image using a define filter. You can try [fspecial()](https://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html#d123e61954) to define your combination of filters. And use [imfilter()](https://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html) to apply the filter to your image.

If you want to do with your own script, you can use these functions to get an idea, but it will be difficult. Likely, you will have to apply some convolution and transformations.